# 6 month rolling data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

This query is currently pulling back 6 month data, so if I run it today I get data from 01/03/2016 to 06/09/2016.  What I would like is the data to stop at 31/08/2016.

And then the following month start at 01/04/2016 to 30/09/2016 and so on.

Many thanks

```
select i.Date 
from table as i
where i.Date >= Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -6,  current_timestamp)), 0)
order by i.Date desc
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (dateadd and datediff are product specific functions.)

Comment: try to use [BETWEEN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try :

```
select i.Date 
from table as i
where i.Date between 
  Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -6,  current_timestamp)), 0) 
  AND DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, 0)
order by i.Date desc
```